# React Context doesn't update all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components which use a HOC to get data from a context Provider.

However, when one child updates the state in the provider, it doesn't seem to update for all components which use the HOC, so the old value is still shown.

Why is this the case, or what am I doing wrong here? How can I get the updated value in all the components?

Stack Snippet for a simple example demonstrating the issue:

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

let UserContext;
const { Provider, Consumer } = (UserContext = React.createContext());

class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Colin",
      setName: this.setName,
    };
  }

  setName = (name) => { 
      this.setState({name});
  }

  render() {
    return <Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</Provider>;
  }
}

const withUser = Component => props => (
  <UserProvider>
    <Consumer>{user => <Component {...user} {...props} />}</Consumer>
  </UserProvider>
);


const TempA = ({name}) => { 
  return <h1>A: {name}</h1>
}

const TempB = ({name, setName}) => { 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <h1>B: {name}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => setName('Ricardo')}>change name</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const A = withUser(TempA);

const B = withUser(TempB);

const App = () => { 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <A />
    <B />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const AppToRender = withUser(App);

render(<AppToRender />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new `Provider` every time you use `withUser`.

If you want to use the same user in the entire app, you can put the `Provider` at the top of your `App` component and only have `withUser` create a new `Consumer`.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const UserContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider, Consumer } = UserContext;

class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Colin",
      setName: this.setName,
    };
  }

  setName = (name) => { 
      this.setState({name});
  }

  render() {
    return <Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</Provider>;
  }
}

const withUser = Component => props => (
  <Consumer>{user => <Component {...user} {...props} />}</Consumer>
);

const TempA = ({name}) => { 
  return <h1>A: {name}</h1>
}

const TempB = ({name, setName}) => { 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <h1>B: {name}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => setName('Ricardo')}>change name</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const A = withUser(TempA);
const B = withUser(TempB);

const App = () => { 
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <A />
      <B />
    </UserProvider>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```